# show many bootstrap tabs that can fit on the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tabs

I have a page design that could potentially show 30+ tabs in the navigation. The tabs are added in dynamically, but I have that figured out already. Is there a standard interface to handle such UI where it will behave like how Firefox is handling with the many tabs with left and right arrows on either side? The left and right arrows will then scroll through the tab list.

Any suggestion would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using jQuery that overflows the extra tabs into a dropdown list..

http://www.bootply.com/115859

Comment: That's a pretty good idea! It works perfectly in Firefox but fails to collapse in IE10 somehow.